# spyOn not working in Http Interceptor in Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to test HttpInterceptor that logs the response of the `http` request. I have a log service that logs the response of the request. The interceptor logs only for GET requeststs.

Here's my interceptor:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LogService } from './log.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoggerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private _log: LogService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        tap(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            if (req.method === 'GET') {
              this._log.log('I was logged');
            }
          }
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Here's the spec file:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController, TestRequest } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HeaderInterceptor } from './add.header.interceptor';
import { LogService } from './log.service';
import { LoggerInterceptor } from './logger.interceptor';

const posts: Array<any> = [
  {
    'userId': 1,
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
    'body': 'quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et '
  },
  {
    'userId': 1,
    'id': 2,
    'title': 'qui est esse',
    'body': 'est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor b'
  }
];

describe('HeaderInterceptor', () => {

  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let logService: LogService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        LogService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoggerInterceptor, multi: true }
      ]
    });

    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    logService = TestBed.get(LogService);
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
  });

  it('must log the http get request', () => {

    const spy = spyOn(logService, 'log');

    httpClient.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe(
        (data: Array<any>) => {
          expect(data.length).toBe(2);
        }
    );

    const req: TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    expect(req.request.headers.has('Content-Type')).toBe(true);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    req.flush(posts);
  });

  it('must log the http post request', () => {

    const spy = spyOn(logService, 'log');

    httpClient.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', posts)
      .subscribe();

    const req: TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    expect(req.request.headers.has('Content-Type')).toBe(true);
    expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    req.flush(posts);
  });
});
```

I have HeaderInterceptor that adds `Content-Type` header to each http request. Testing of that interceptor works fine.

When I tried to test the LoggerInterceptor, I get error on the spy         `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Here's the error:

```
Error: Expected spy log to have been called.
    at stack (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2455:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2425:14)
    at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:901:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:524:34)
    at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:845:21)
    at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalled (http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/pritambohra/Desktop/testing-in-angular/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2369:12)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/src/app/logger.interceptor.spec.ts?:57:17)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:388:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:288:1)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:1)
```

Not really sure where I am going wrong. I am executing the post http call for the sake of code-coverage. What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This might only be a partial answer.

I am not expert in testing, so I shouldn't try to explain **why** your code failing, but I believe the code below is correct and doing true tests.

IMO there are two problems in your code in the GET case:
- you are flushing after expecting the spy - should be the other way around
- you are not calling `done()` from within `.subscribe()`

Your code for POST case seems to work ok though (except that the test description seems incorrect, shouldn't it be "should NOT log" instead?)

I have left out the check of `Content-Type` header as it was failing for some reason (don't have time to investigate it further - will be curious to see if you solve it) and it was not part of your question.

```
describe('Logger Interceptor', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let logService: LogService;
  let spy: Function;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: LoggerInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    });

    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    logService = TestBed.get(LogService);
    spy = spyOn(logService, 'log');
  });

  afterEach(() => httpMock.verify());

  it('must log the http get request', (done) => {

    httpClient.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(2);
      done();
    });

    const req: TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

    req.flush(posts);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should NOT log the http post request', () => {

    httpClient.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', posts)
      .subscribe();

    const req: TestRequest = httpMock.expectOne('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    req.flush(posts);
  });
});
```

I would be curious to hear why the GET case requires the above changes, should anyone be able to explain.